# Keep all images centered and separate

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to keep 3 images centered in the middle of the window regardless of the size of the window. When I resize the window the images collapse onto each other and get squashed.

```html
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        display: table;
    }
    .my-block {
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) ; margin: 0px;" />
<div>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png" style="position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" />
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png" style="position: absolute; top: 60%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); " />
</div>
```

Comment: Ignore the margin:0px it was just a trial

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in Chrome. They appear vertically-staggered at all screen sizes.

Comment: I ran that in Firefox and they all stayed horizontally centered not matter what size I made the window.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep all three images centered – vertically and horizontally – in all window sizes, with just a few lines of code using [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png"> 
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png"> 
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body { height: 100%;}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;    /* center images vertically (in this case) */
    align-items: center;        /* center images horizontally (in this case) */
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6wn1p8u/3/)

---

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't want to learn a new framework right now..... This will resize the images and keep them in the middle. vw stands for viewport width. vh is viewport height units. Here we will make sure that regardless of the window size, the image will always be 30% of the screen. the height will always be 20% of the height of the screen. Then we give the first image an explicit margin from the nearest sibling. Mess with the width, height, and first elements top margin to get exactly what you want.
>   JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrvustpa/ or maybe you like https://jsfiddle.net/xrvustpa/3/ better. Like I said. Mess with the values. Simple and concise.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        display: table;
    }
    img {
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 20vh;
    }

</style>


<div class="my-block">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png" style="margin-top:20vh"/>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png"  />
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png" />
</div>
```